# How can i remove minutes or disable minutes from my time zone using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js in date range picker I want to hide or disable my minutes hand. What can i do, here is my code which I tried :

```js
function cb(start, end) {
  $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh'));
  $('#hidreportrange').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh'));
  var selecteddate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh');
  var con = new Date(selecteddate);
  var datestring = con.toString();
  $("#spnseldate").html(datestring.split(" ")[2] + " " + datestring.split(" ")[1] + " " + datestring.split(" ")[3]);

  // $("#spncurrentDate").html(DataBaseManager.DateTimeFormat(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')));
}
```

Comment: you have to pass your date in moment function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    
    function abc(start,end){
        console.log(moment(start).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'),moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    }
   
    abc(new Date(),new Date());
   
</script>
```

you can use like that if you are using moment.js then you have to pass your date
in that function.